# hide and show element depending of the value of radio-button using dom scripting javascript

Tags: javascript, function, radio-button, show-hide

Hello everyone I am trying to find a way to show and hide this span with id "answer1" [Your main risk factors are your BMI and your diet.] depending on the radio button of class"button" (value superior or equal to 10). if the button is checked  the message span id"answer1" should be displayed if not the span id "answer1" is hidden. 
here my script

```
function addNumbers() {
    var selectedRadios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked');
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedRadios.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(selectedRadios[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('answer').value = sum;
    var showDiv = sum < 15 ? "lowResult" : (sum < 25 ? "mediumResult" : "highRisk");
    document.getElementById(showDiv).style.display = 'block';
}

var text = document.getElementsById("answer1");
var butt = document.getElementsByClassName("button");

window.onload = start();

function start(){
     for (i=0; i<text.length; i++){
        text[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
     };
};

butt[i].onclick = function (){
    if (text[i].style.visibility = "hidden"){
        text[i].style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        text[i].style.visibility = "hidden"
    };
};
```

here my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="diabeteStool.css" >
    <script src="diabeteStool.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table>

<tr>
<th scope="col"></th>
<th scope="col">noRisk</th>
<th scope="col">lowRisk</th>
 <th scope="col">mediumRisk</th>
 <th scope="col">HighRisk</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <th scope="row">
  <div class="lefttext">How old are you?</div>
 </th>

 <td>
   <input type="radio" id="value1" name="selectedAge" value="0" checked>1-  25</td>
  <td>
  <input type="radio" id="value1" name="selectedAge" value="5">26-40</td>
  <td>
  <input type="radio" id="value1" name="selectedAge" value="8">41-60</td>
  <td>
   <input class="button" type="radio" id="value1" name="selectedAge"  value="10">1-25</td>
  </tr>

 <tr>
 <th scope="row">
  <div class="lefttext">What is you BMI?</div>
  </th>
  <td>
  <input type="radio" id="value2" name="selectedBmi" value="0" checked>0-25</td>
 <td>
  <input type="radio" id="value2" name="selectedBmi" value="0">26-30</td>
 <td>
  <input type="radio" id="value2" name="selectedBmi" value="9">31-35</td>
 <td>
  <input class="button" type="radio" id="value2" name="selectedBmi" value="10">35+</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <th scope="row">
  <div class="lefttext">Does anybody in your family have diabetes?</div>
 </th>
 <td>
  <input type="radio" id="value3" name="selectedDiabete" value="0" checked>No</td>
 <td>
  <input type="radio" id="value3" name="selectedDiabete" value="7">Grandparent</td>
<td>
  <input type="radio" id="value3" name="selectedDiabete" value="15">Sibling</td>
 <td>
  <input class="button" type="radio" id="value3" name="selectedDiabete" value="15">Parent</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <th scope="row">
  <div class="lefttext">How would you describe your diabete</div>
</th>
<td>
  <input type="radio" id="value4" name="description" value="0" checked>Low sugar</td>
<td>
  <input type="radio" id="value4" name="description" value="0">Normal sugar</td>
<td>
  <input type="radio" id="value4" name="description" value="7">Quite high sugar</td>
<td>
  <input class="button" type="radio" id="value4" name="description" value="10">High sugar</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit"   onclick="javascript:addNumbers()" />Total =
```

```
<section>
<h2>Your results:</h2>
<div class="results" id="lowResult">
<p>Your results show that you currently have a low risk of developing diabetes. However, it is important that you maintain a healthy lifestyle in terms of diet and exercise.
</p>
</div>
<div class="results" id="mediumResult">
<p>Your results show that you currently have a medium risk of developing diabetes. For more information on your risk factors, and what to do about them, please visit our diabetes advice website at <a href="http://www.zha.org.zd">http://www.zha.org.zd</a>.
  <p>
 </div>
<div class="results" id="highRisk">
<p>Your results show that you currently have a HIGH risk of developing diabetes. <span id="answer1" ">[Your main risk factors are your BMI and your diet.] </span> We advise that you contact the Health Authority to discuss your risk factors as soon as you can. Please fill in our
  contact form and a member of the Health Authority Diabetes Team will be in contact with you.
 </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is exactly your problem? It is better if you cleary specify the problem. What have you tried already? Have you checked in the Developer Console if there are any errors in your code?

Comment: please, specify what you've tried

Comment: the problem is that the function shows the message span even if the class button is not checked

Comment: function ShowRisk(){
var selectedRadios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked');
  var risk = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < selectedRadios.length; i++) {
  risk+= parseInt(selectedRadios[i].value>=10);
  }
  document.getElementByClassName('button').value = risk;
  var showAdvice = risk >= 10 ? 'answer1';
  document.getElementById(showAdvice).style.display = 'block';
  }

Answer (score 0):

@martin this means an assignment, `=`,  but this means to test if the values are equal `==` (also `===` checks if both type and value are equal.

So your line

```
if (text[i].style.visibility = "hidden"){
```

will ignore the existing value of `text[i].style.visibility` - instead it will interpret it as **if the value can be successfully set** - which will then execute the `if` statement.

Change it to

```
if (text[i].style.visibility == "hidden"){
```

BTW you can edit the original question to add the function in your comments.